# Class method in enhanced for loop

Tags: java, class, for-loop, methods, foreach

I need to draw my buttons in the screen, but when using the for loop enhanced,

```
public void update(){
  for(Button bt: button){
    bt.update();
  }
}
```

an error is pointed in the 3rd line (code box above). I don't know what is wrong, neither an alternative way to update/draw the buttons. I tried using the "normal for loop", and the same line is marked.

the console output below:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gameState.FirstScreenState.update(FirstScreenState.java:55)
    at main.GamePanel.update(GamePanel.java:96)
    at main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:71)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Should `button` contain null references?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan how can I add this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `button` collection/array contains a `null`.

I strongly recommend renaming `button` to `buttons`.